# Relative clause (reference of "which")

Tags: relative-clauses

> They've asked him to mend the fuse, which he won't even try.

From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, which deems it as ungrammatical, without further explanation. I think that "which" could refer to "to mend the fuse":
which he won't even try = he won't even try to mend the fuse.

Do I get it wrong？Could you please tell me how to revise the sentence?

Context (summarized from the book):

> 1. They’ve asked me to mend the fuse, **but** I **can’t**.
> 2. They’ve asked him to mend the fuse, **but** he won’t even try.

The relative counterpart for (1):

> 1a. They've asked me to mend the fuse, **which** I can't.

But there is no comparative counterpart for (2).

> 2a. *They’ve asked him to mend the fuse, **which** he won’t even try.

Comment: What page number(s) in CGEL?

Comment: @Billj  It's on 1528.

Comment: The rule is that 'gap' can represent a complement of an auxiliary verb, as in 1a. but not of a lexical verb, as in 2a. So we can have "They've asked me to mend the fuse, which I **can't** __", but not *"They’ve asked him to mend the fuse, which he won’t even **try** __".

Comment: yes,  I can follow those examples in CGEL.  But I'm just wondering if native speakers really find 2a unacceptable.

Comment: Probably not. It's quite an obscure 'rule'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence is clear, and it might even be used in casual speech. I think the problem is that, strictly speaking, *which* appears to refer to the fuse rather than the action of mending it (he won't try the fuse). It would be more correct to say:

> They've asked him to mend the fuse, which he won't even try to do.

Does this make sense in relation to what your grammar book is discussing?

Comment: Thanks, I think so. I've edited to provide some context.

Answer (score 0):

"To mend the fuse" is an infinitive phrase acts as an adverb modifying the finite verb "asked".  If this is followed by a relative clause, the relative clause can only modify the noun it follows i.e. the fuse.  A relative clause cannot modify an adverb.